# Are recursive retries in user applications dangerous?

Tags: c++, security, recursion, stack-overflow

Whilst writing a section of my application which requires the user to enter their current password, I was wondering if it was dangerous to do something like the following (in the function `OnChangePassword()`:

```
if( strCurrPassword != inputPassword.GetInput() )
{
    if( MessageBox( _T("Incorrect password entered, you must enter your current password"), _T("Incorrect Password"), MB_RETRYCANCEL | MB_ICONWARNING ) == IDRETRY )
        OnChangePassword();

    return;
}
```

This would be fine in the usual case, as the user would generally just require a few attempts before he/she remembered their password. However, I was concerned that this could be abused by a malicious user and used to cause a call stack overflow.

If it could be used to cause a stack overflow, what measures could I take to prevent this from being abused?

Comment: Well, you _could_ add a parameter counting the tries (e.g. `OnChangePassword(unsigned int numTries)` and abort recursion after a certain number of tries. Or just don't use recursion, but a loop.

Answer (score 2):

you should limit the number of consecutive attempts at entering a password anyway as a precaution against brute-force attacks. considering the code in isolation, an additional parameter to `OnChangePassword` reflecting the recursion depth would probably suffice, throwing an error message if it exceeds some limit.

i wouldn't regard a stack overflow as a primary concern. realistically that would occur only if the code was exposed to some brute force attempt of cracking the password.

having said this, an attack vector could be to deliberately strip the system of resources such as available stack space (eg. by an equivalent of dos attacks), then trying to provoke a stack overflow by requesting another processing task on top - a task that might be your password checker (the scenario feels rather esoteric as i write it down).

Answer (score 0):

Recursion routines usually have some method of exiting the recursion and as @collapsar states, for security you should have a limited number of retries.

In considering security, the stack overflow isn't the only issue. It would also be better if you inline the code and don't put it in a function that has an obvious name such as OnChangePassword. It wouldn't be too difficult for someone to search for a symbol containing 'Password' in your executable and then bypass the intended verification of the password.

Alternatively, an attacker could just look for code around the function that handles the GetInput() to find where your code is checking and comparing it with the password, so perhaps you want to think about handling this differently, but that can be left for another SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You can post a `WM_COMMAND` message using `PostMessage()` to generate the click event for `ChangePassword`.  That way there is no need to call `OnChangePassword` recursively.